# How can I debug which dependency modifies Date.prototype.toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript

**Background:**

I used the `Litepicker` library in my project and spotted a bug where displayed month names are off by one. E.g. "February" is labelled "January". The dates are exported correctly. It is not a problem with months starting from zero. Only translations are "off by one".

When I tried to reproduce the issue, it looks like `Litepicker` works correctly. The documentation says it uses `Date.prototype.toLocaleString()` internally, so I believe one of our dependencies modifies it.

**Question:**

How can I check which dependency/piece of code modifies `Date.prototype`? Is there a reflection mechanism that could tell me who tinkered with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toLocaleString', {
  set(newValue) {
    console.log('Tries to modify Date.prototype.toLocaleString');
    console.trace();
  }
})
```

Comment: Bonus question: I build the project with yarn with `application.js` as the main entry. Where do I put that code so that it is evaluated before everything else? If I put it at the beginning of `application.js` the dependencies already modified the `Date`, right?

Comment: yes, you should place it in the main entry before importing any dependencies. But you can also create a new file and import it with node -r flag (https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_r_require_module)